# What to change in PHP file(s) when responsiveness not working due to "forwarding with masking"

Tags: php, css, joomla, responsive-design

I am forwarding a domain name to another domain where my Joomla template is hosted. I am using "forwarding with masking" so that the company's proper name is displayed in the address bar. The Joomla template is responsive and looks great when no masking is used. But when masking is used the responsiveness is lost and the template appears as it would on desktop.

I have done some research and it apparently has to do with the way masking works....either an iFrame or viewport(?) is used to display the actual site inside the browser which shows the pointed domain. This way the addressbar shows the original domain and not the one its pointing to.  For some reason this causes the responsive CSS to NOT get "triggered."

Does anyone have experience with this and know of a change that could be made to the index.php file or something to ensure the responsiveness still works with forwarding with masking.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you have some examples ? or some codes ?

Comment: I'm not even sure what file I would change so I wouldn't know what code to show you.